# getArgs() is null in fragment on fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to have an information fragment on a sliding tab fragment, and be able to pass in some parameter to the information fragment when creating it. I've put (hopefully all) the relevant code below:

InfoFragment.java:

```
public class InfoFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String HEADER_ARG = "HEADER";
    private String header;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment using the provided parameters.
     */
    public static InfoFragment newInstance(String header)
    {
        InfoFragment fragment = new InfoFragment ();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(HEADER_ARG, header);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * Required empty public constructor
     */
    public InfoFragment() {}

    /**
     * Gets the args out of the bundle
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
        {
            this.header = getArguments().getString(HEADER_ARG);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("Frag", "Args = null");
        }
    }

    // Rest of Fragment...
}
```

TabFragment.java:

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment
{
    /**
     * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
     */
    public TabFragment() {}

    /**
     * Create the Inventories tab view
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_2, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    /**
     * Dynamically add fragments
     */
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        InfoFragment infoFrag = InfoFragment.newInstance("MyHeader");
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.info_fragment, infoFrag);
    }

    // Rest of TabFragment...
}
```

tab_fragment.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/character_item_fragment_1"
        android:name="lomax.mycharacter3.InfoFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The console log shows that the getArgs() = null, and I have no idea why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using fragment tag, your fragment will be instantiated using empty constructor, also you forgot to call commit at the end on transaction, that's why you didn't get exception about view with missing id.

Fixed version:
tab_fragment.xml:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/info_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Code:

```
InfoFragment infoFrag = InfoFragment.newInstance("MyHeader");
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.info_fragment, infoFrag).commit();
```

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely correct! Thank you kind sir/madam :D